# Remote Debugging

Tags: android, testing, remote-debugging

I have an android app which works perfectly on all the available devices with me. But the Client gave a list of devices in which app didn't work. Is there some remote debugging tool? So that I can ask them to connect their mobiles and debug remotely?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en

Comment: @TerrilThomas I guess it only gives logcat. I am thinking of some tool which allows line by line tracing and debugging

Comment: but in the logcat u'll get the log as where ur app is crashing on that particular device.

Comment: Note.  aLogCat won't work without additional steps on Jelly Bean.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/issues/detail?id=42

Answer (score 2):

I would advise the use of TestDroid.com It isn't the most efficient tool, but allows you control physical devices and view the output through the browser.

If you have the budget Bugfinders provides an excellent testing service testing on hundreds of devices in hundreds of locations using crowd-testing.

Alternatively testing in an emulator will provide semi-accurate results, but should be fine depending on the bug.